# How get access all user attributes available in OID/OAM within Weblogic Security Realm?

Tags: java, security, attributes, weblogic, oid

We have configured OID/OAM as our security providers in weblogic security.

On checking user attributes, only user id is visible.

How to get all attributes available in OID/OAM to available in Weblogic Security User and Groups?

Comment: We had a similar problem and there does not seem to be an easy way. What we did was getting the ldap connection from Weblogic and extracting the attributes using JNDI. Though I have to admit, that is not pretty

Comment: Thanks Slettal..!!Do you mind sharing some reference on how it was achieved?

Comment: Most of the code is in parts from Oracle Tutorials, posted it all as an answers because.. more space :)

Answer (score 1):

Short Version: Use JMX as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/e13728/editsecurity.htm#JMXCU206) to get the configured OID-Authenticator-MBean. You can then use that MBean to get the necessary parameters to establish your own Connection to the OID and traverse the attributes. You might also want to read about Java Naming and Directory Operations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/ops/getattrs.html)

Sample Implementation:

```
package test;

import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.management.Descriptor;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.management.modelmbean.ModelMBeanInfo;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;

public class OIDFromWLBean {

    // The attribute you want to read (for a specific user)
    private static final String ATTRIBUTE_NAME = "pwdChangedTime";

    // The Class of the configured Authenticator Provider, here it is OID
    // Check the API if you use something else
    // API Docs:
    // http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/security/providers/authentication/OracleInternetDirectoryAuthenticatorMBean.html
    final String OID_AUTHENTICATOR_MBEAN_NAME = "weblogic.security.providers.authentication.OracleInternetDirectoryAuthenticatorMBean";

    // The rest here should be static and stay unchanged
    private static final String COM_SUN_JNDI_LDAP_LDAP_CTX_FACTORY = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    private static final String INTERFACE_CLASS_NAME = "interfaceClassName";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDERS = "AuthenticationProviders";
    private static final String DEFAULT_REALM = "DefaultRealm";
    private static final String SECURITY_CONFIGURATION = "SecurityConfiguration";
    private static final String DOMAIN_CONFIGURATION = "DomainConfiguration";
    final String MBEAN_SERVER = "java:comp/env/jmx/domainRuntime";
    final String DOMAIN_MBEAN_NAME = "com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean";

    public String getAttribute(String username, String password) {
    final MBeanServer connection = getConnection();
    final ObjectName defaultAuthenticator = getAuthenticator(connection);

    String rest = null;
    try {
        String host = getHost(defaultAuthenticator, connection);
        String port = getPort(defaultAuthenticator, connection);
        String userBaseDN = getUserBaseDN(defaultAuthenticator, connection);
        DirContext ctx = getConnectionLdapOid(username, password, host, port, userBaseDN);
        rest = getAttribute(ctx, "cn=" + username + "," + userBaseDN, username);
    } catch (Exception ref) {
        // Do something to handle that
    }
    return rest;
    }

    private MBeanServer getConnection() {
    MBeanServer connection;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        connection = (MBeanServer) ctx.lookup(MBEAN_SERVER);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return connection;
    }

    private ObjectName getAuthenticator(MBeanServer connection) {
    ObjectName authenticator = null;
    ObjectName[] authenticationProviders;
    try {
        ObjectName configurationMBeans = new ObjectName(DOMAIN_MBEAN_NAME);
        ObjectName domain = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(configurationMBeans, DOMAIN_CONFIGURATION);

        ObjectName security = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(domain, SECURITY_CONFIGURATION);

        ObjectName realm = (ObjectName) connection.getAttribute(security, DEFAULT_REALM);

        authenticationProviders = (ObjectName[]) connection.getAttribute(realm, AUTHENTICATION_PROVIDERS);

        for (int p = 0; p < authenticationProviders.length; p++) {

        ModelMBeanInfo info = (ModelMBeanInfo) connection.getMBeanInfo(authenticationProviders[p]);
        Descriptor desc = info.getMBeanDescriptor();
        String className = (String) desc.getFieldValue(INTERFACE_CLASS_NAME);

        if (className.equals(OID_AUTHENTICATOR_MBEAN_NAME)) {
            authenticator = authenticationProviders[p];
            break;
        }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something to handle that
    }
    return authenticator;
    }


    private DirContext getConnectionLdapOid(String username, String password, String host, String port, String userBaseDN) throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> jndiProps = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, COM_SUN_JNDI_LDAP_LDAP_CTX_FACTORY);
    jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + host + ":" + port);
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=" + username + "," + userBaseDN);
    jndiProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(jndiProps);
    return ctx;
    }

    private String getHost(ObjectName defaultAuthenticator, MBeanServer connection) throws Exception {
    String result = (String) connection.getAttribute(defaultAuthenticator, "Host");
    return result;
    }

    private String getPort(ObjectName defaultAuthenticator, MBeanServer connection) throws Exception {
    String result = ((Integer) connection.getAttribute(defaultAuthenticator, "Port")).toString();
    return result;
    }

    private String getUserBaseDN(ObjectName defaultAuthenticator, MBeanServer connection) throws Exception {
    String result = (String) connection.getAttribute(defaultAuthenticator, "UserBaseDN");
    return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static String getAttribute(DirContext ctx, String DN, String user) {
    String attrName, attrValue = "";
    String result = null;
    try {
        SearchControls ctls = new SearchControls();
        ctls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.OBJECT_SCOPE);
        ctls.setReturningAttributes(new String[0]);
        NamingEnumeration sre = null;
        sre = ctx.search(DN, "cn=" + user, ctls);
        if (!(sre != null && sre.hasMoreElements())) {
        return null;
        }
        Attributes attrs = null;
        String returnAttrs[] = { ATTRIBUTE_NAME };
        attrs = ctx.getAttributes(DN, returnAttrs);
        NamingEnumeration enu = attrs.getAll();
        if ((enu != null) && enu.hasMore()) {
        Attribute attr = (Attribute) enu.next();
        attrName = attr.getID();
        NamingEnumeration attrValues = attr.getAll();
        if (attrValues.hasMore()) {
            attrValue = (String) attrValues.next();
        }
        }
        result = attrValue;
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // Do something to handle that
    }
    return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a star..!! I will give this a try. Seems to work for us.. In any case, thanks a ton for your help and effort.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Might save me :)